# Extended permutations, how does it work mathematically if you keep adding categories?

Tags: probability-theory, logic, permutations, combinations

I'm a little bit unsure how to approach this problem of permutations when you add categories:

Each object can contain 3 attributes out of the 10 possible available.

Because order doesn't matter, there would be 10 x 9 x 8 = 720 possible choices. If duplications of attributes don't matter (eg. you can have 3 of the same attribute), then there will be 10 x 10 x 10 possible choices. This part is easy.

But what I don't understand, is what happens if this object can randomly come from any of 30 countries?

And what if this object can be of any 5 sizes?

How many possibilities are there?

Comment: I'm confused about what you are asking. An object has 3 out of 10 of a list of possible attributes, in addition to a size and a country? Or are size and country some of the possible attributes?

Comment: yes, in addition. Size and country are not an attribute.

Comment: @Useless, what do you think? :)